# Unable to connect to parse after recent update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

Since the latest update, I get the error

> "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>   (lldb)"

whenever I try to connect to parse

I can't even perform a simple task like create a user, as it will always crash. I suspect something changed after Xcode's recent update, and I cannot figure out what it is.

I suspect it could be the `libc++abi.dylib` library not been supported, but I don't know what to do about this.

Here's my View controller

```
import UIKit

import Parse



class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet var username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!



func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}



@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {

if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

displayAlert(title: "Error in Form", message: "Please fill in the information")

} else {

let user = PFUser()

user.username = username.text

user.password = password.text

}

}



Here's my App Delegate

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

//--------------------------------------

// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate

//--------------------------------------

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

// Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.

// Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.

Parse.enableLocalDatastore()



let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in

ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "......"

ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "......"

ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "........"

})



Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)
```

Here's the error

> 019-05-22 12:51:10.776625+0200
>   ParseStarterProject-Swift[18144:1046582] [MC] System group container
>   for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/ejike/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8AAB1103-8B3E-4584-BFAE-170720DE4BEF/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2019-05-22 12:51:10.780381+0200
>   ParseStarterProject-Swift[18144:1046582] [MC] Reading from private
>   effective user settings.
>
> 2019-05-22 12:51:23.291890+0200
>   ParseStarterProject-Swift[18144:1046582] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The
>   class PFUser must be registered with registerSubclass before using
>   Parse.'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (
>
> 0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107dad6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
>
> 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000107351ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
>
> 2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107dad555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
>
> 3 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f5a7e1 -[PFObject init] + 189
>
> 4 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f26533 $sSo6PFUserCABycfcTO +
>   19
>
> 5 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f25bdf $sSo6PFUserCABycfC + 31
>
> 6 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f25647
>   $s25ParseStarterProject_Swift14ViewControllerC6signupyyypF + 1383
>
> 7 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f25c3c
>   $s25ParseStarterProject_Swift14ViewControllerC6signupyyypFTo + 76
>
> 8 UIKitCore 0x0000000114799204 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>
> 9 UIKitCore 0x00000001141eec19 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] +
>   67
>
> 10 UIKitCore 0x00000001141eef36 -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
>
> 11 UIKitCore 0x00000001141edeec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] +
>   583
>
> 12 UIKitCore 0x00000001147d1eee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] +
>   2547
>
> 13 UIKitCore 0x00000001147d35d2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4079
>
> 14 UIKitCore 0x00000001147b1d16 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
>
> 15 UIKitCore 0x0000000114882293
>   __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3232
>
> 16 UIKitCore 0x0000000114884bb9 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5911
>
> 17 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107d14be1
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>
> 18 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107d14463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
>
> 19 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107d0eb1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
>
> 20 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107d0e302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
>
> 21 GraphicsServices 0x000000010cf112fe GSEventRunModal + 65
>
> 22 UIKitCore 0x0000000114797ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
>
> 23 ParseStarterProject-Swift 0x0000000105f27dab main + 75
>
> 24 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001091a3541 start + 1
>
> 25 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>
> )
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>
> (lldb)

Comment: Can you put up an example project? I am working on a project using Parse right now and can help you get past this. I’m using latest Xcode and latest parse version.

Comment: Yes. You can just create a GitHub repo and send me the link.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, here's the link to the GitHub repo
https://github.com/kciano/ParseServerStarterProject-

Comment: do you mind if I convert to pods instead of static frameworks?

Comment: sure you very much can

Comment: Sorry man had a close friend go through some stuff and had to visit. Back into it now, will get this across to you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, really appreciate